# How to create a class whose instances will contain a self referencing attribute?

Tags: python, class

I think I can best explain what I'm trying to do on an example.

So, in C++ I could do sth like that:

```
#include <iostream>

class Cl
{
public:
    Cl* recref = this;
    int i = 5;
} ob;

int main()
{
    std::cout << ob.recref->i << '\n';
}
```

But in Python I can't do this:

```
class Cl:
    recref = self
```

There is no `self` in class scope defined.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want a a class variable point to a single instance? Singleton?  If so set it in the '\__init__'

Answer (score 2):

I don't know C++ code, what you trying to achieve but in python:

```
In [81]: class Cl:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.recref = self
```

Is the way to use `self`.